# How can we specify the execution time for any virtual machine (vm) in cloudsim simulator

Tags: java, virtual-machine, scheduled-tasks, round-robin, cloudsim

if we have 50 cloudlets/tasks and 1 virtual machine (vm) 
how can we make vm to run for specific time 
in order to apply RR method and cloudelts are run in time slice or quantum

Answer (score 0):

In fact, CloudletSchedulers in CloudSim don't implement the concept of time slice/quantum.

If you need to assess Cloudlets' preemption process, you can check [CloudSim Plus](http://cloudsimplus.org), it's a full-featured, state-of-the-art, completely re-engineered and actively maintained CloudSim fork. It provides an implementation of the Completely Fair Linux Scheduler that performs actual preemption and considers a time slice/quantum to run Cloudlets. Check the [CloudletSchedulerCompletelyFair](https://github.com/manoelcampos/cloudsim-plus/blob/master/cloudsim-plus/src/main/java/org/cloudbus/cloudsim/schedulers/cloudlet/CloudletSchedulerCompletelyFair.java) and the [LinuxCompletelyFairSchedulerExample](https://github.com/manoelcampos/cloudsim-plus/blob/master/cloudsim-plus-examples/src/main/java/org/cloudsimplus/examples/schedulers/LinuxCompletelyFairSchedulerExample.java).